# Probability of pulling out white and black balls from a jar

Tags: probability

A jar contains $a$ white balls and $b$ black balls. 
Two players pull out the balls in turn (one by one).

The first who pulls out a white ball wins the game.

I'm trying to find the probability  of that the first player wins the game.

Thank you

Comment: Have tried working it out for a and b small?

Comment: @KitterCatter what do you mean a and b small?

Comment: Like a =1 and b=1. Then working from there. It might help you build an intuition.

Comment: I'm trying that. i think its really depending of who is bigger a or b

Comment: Notice anything so far? Any general increase or decrease?

Comment: not really so far :(

Answer (score 2):

The probability that the first player wins on his first draw is $$\frac{a}{a+b}.$$ 
The probability that the first player wins on his second draw is $$\frac{b}{a+b} \frac{b-1}{a+b-1} \frac{a}{a+b-2} = \frac{ ab(b-1)}{(a+b)(a+b-1)(a+b-2)} = \frac{a}{a+b} \frac{{ b \choose 2} }{ {a+b-1 \choose 2}}. $$
The probability that the first player wins on his third draw is 
$$ \frac{b}{a+b} \frac{b-1}{a+b-1} \frac{ b-2}{a+b-2} \frac{ b-3}{ a+ b-3} \frac{a}{a+b-4} = \frac{a}{a+b} \frac{{ b \choose 4} }{ {a+b-1 \choose 4}}. $$
And so on.

Now all the above events of the first player winning are mutually exclusive. So the total probability of the first player winning is 
$$ \frac{a}{a+b} \sum_{k=0}^{\min \left\{ \left\lfloor \frac{b}{2} \right\rfloor,  \left\lfloor \frac{a+ b -1 }{2} \right\rfloor\right\}} \frac{ { b \choose 2k }}{{a+b-1 \choose 2k }}.$$